# Issue with making a USB persistent

Tags: bash, persistence

I'm trying to make a USB persistent with this tutorial http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence.

Problem: I don't know what the following means (is it bash ?) and where should I use it (into the Live OS or outside ?)

```
end=7gb
read start _ < <(du -bcm kali-linux-1.0.8-amd64.iso | tail -1); echo $start
parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary $start $end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are commands to run from your terminal window which is probably running bash and has the bash prompt displayed. From the step 1 instructions, it points you to another url and that page leaves you with a terminal window open.

Copy and paste them one at a time in your window.

The 1st line sets a "end" variable to 7gb, which presumes your USB is 8gb.

The 2nd line sets a "start" variable (and an _ variable) to the size of the iso. The last line contains some number followed by "total". The number goes in "start", and the string "total" goes in _ (essentially a don't care).

The 3rd line runs the parted command passing in the start and end variable values.